# On Demand Resources (iOS9) Issue

Tags: ios9, one-definition-rule, on-demand-resources, app-thinning

I'm planning to use the new (iOS9) feature "On Demand Resources" in my app with the aim to reduce the overall size.
All things work well but when I test my app using Testflight, I see that the amount of assets that should be download only on demand (about 30mb) are instead downloaded at installation time and are seen by iOS as "Documents and Data".

So my app that should be about 95 mb is instead more than 125Mb (95 mb + 30 mb (of "Documents and Data")).
Any suggestions?  Anyone has observed the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode->Build Settings -> Assets ->Embed Asset Packs in Product Bundle : is it set to Yes?  This might be causing the assets to be packaged into the main product bundle and downloaded instead of being kept separate.

Comment: What it (Embed Asset Packs in Product Bundle) should be? Yes/No? I have enabled bitcode and demand resource. But still not getting reduced app. Please help.